# How can I close the browser launched by url_launcher? Or re-focus my app?

Tags: flutter

I'm using [url_launcher](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/url_launcher) to complete oauth authentication. I open a url for the user, they complete authentication, but then the user has to manually return to my app from the browser.

Can I close the browser for the user? If not, can I make my app refocus on the user's device so they're returned to my app?

Comment: have you found a working solution? I'm stuck in the same situation

Comment: Mmmm... Kind of. My solution was just to display a message saying "Thanks. You can close this page now." Because I couldn't find another way. Lots of other popular apps do that anyways.

Comment: Did you use Oauth2 package?

Comment: I am using url_launcher for oauth too and we have on successful auth a redirect to a deeplink which closes the webview, refocusing the app again.

Answer (score 6):

You can do it by calling :

`await closeWebView();`

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work on Windows Desktop, only on iOS and Android
UnimplementedError: closeWebView() has not been implemented.
#0      UrlLauncherPlatform.closeWebView

Comment: Does not work on Chrome in Android either, only Safari in IOS

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Guy's comment: Deeplink is the thing you are looking for:

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/navigation/deep-linking

In you `Androidmanifest.xml`:

```
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="APPNAME" />
</intent-filter>
```

Let your OAuth service redirect to your backend to call the deep link or directly call the deep link. In your backend send a redirect like this `APPNAME://APPROUTE` or provide a button with a `data-link`. In my case I am using MVC dotnet:

```
return Redirect("dashpit://drawer");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
import 'package:url_launcher/src/url_launcher_uri.dart' as url_launcher;
```

instead of:

```
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher_string.dart' as url_launcher;
```